# Zeal not working on my Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys

I installed it with given procedure on http://zealdocs.org/. 
It is showing some error. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I know Zeal uses <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space bar</kbd>. I think there is clash of some similar keyboard shortcuts. So I have changed keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space bar</kbd> from system setting (so that Zeal can use it). But then also it is not working.
I googled for issue but could not find solution for it. Help me please

Comment: You have to install Qt5 first. http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Comment: So how was I able to take screen-shot of the application? In order to install this application we are required to install Qt5.